# Sudoers overwritten by unknown instance

Tags: fedora, security, sudo, sudoedit

After `org.kde.pim.aconadiserver` crashed on my Fedora 25 workstation after running `pkill` to get the progress of a dd copy and Kde did a slow restart after some time, I could not use `sudo` with my normal user anymore.

The answer was **`user is NOT in the sudoers file`** altough it clearly was before and I definately could use `sudo` before. I had to edit the sudoers file with the root user. It didn't have new user entries, it seemed to be a default file.

Because I edited the sudoers file now, I currently have no idea how to figure out when exactly it was changed and especially what changed it.

Could dnf have overwritten it in an update? And is there a way to check that (in archlinux(pacman) you can search the install scripts, maybe it is possible with dnf too?)? But the latest dnf upgrade was a week before the incident, and the last install wasat least 12 hours before the incident. And `sudo` was still working. Maybe the script was run after the crash, maybe a setup script for a KDE component? Or might the crash of akonadiserver or the KDE restart have caused that?

**Extract of journalctl when the crash happend:**

```
Sep 15 00:00:35 hostname sudo[29889]:     rudi : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/somefolder ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/pkill dd -USR1
Sep 15 00:00:36 hostname sudo[29889]: pam_systemd(sudo:session): Cannot create session: Already occupied by a session
Sep 15 00:00:36 hostname sudo[29889]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep 15 00:00:36 hostname sudo[29889]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep 15 00:00:37 hostname systemd[1]: sddm.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=10/USR1
Sep 15 00:00:37 hostname systemd-logind[1049]: Removed session 2.
Sep 15 00:00:37 hostname kdeinit5[1685]: kdeinit5: Fatal IO error: client killed
Sep 15 00:00:40 hostname audit[4570]: ANOM_ABEND auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 pid=4570 comm="TaskSchedulerSe" exe=2F6F70742F676
Sep 15 00:00:40 hostname audit[2462]: ANOM_ABEND auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 pid=2462 comm="TaskSchedulerSe" exe=2F6F70742F676
Sep 15 00:00:40 hostname audit[12260]: ANOM_ABEND auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 pid=12260 comm="TaskSchedulerSe" exe=2F6F70742F6
Sep 15 00:00:40 hostname audit[12435]: ANOM_ABEND auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 pid=12435 comm="TaskSchedulerSe" exe=2F6F70742F6
Sep 15 00:00:44 hostname at-spi-bus-launcher[1936]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
Sep 15 00:00:44 hostname at-spi-bus-launcher[1936]:       after 666960 requests (666960 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Sep 15 00:00:39 hostname polkitd[1107]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:2 (system bus name :1.37, object path /org/kde/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale de_AT.UTF-8) (
Sep 15 00:00:37 hostname kdeinit5[1685]: kdeinit5: sending SIGHUP to children.
Sep 15 00:00:38 hostname systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Sep 15 00:00:39 hostname kdeinit5[1685]: kdeinit5: sending SIGTERM to children.
Sep 15 00:00:39 hostname kdeinit5[1685]: kdeinit5: Exit.
Sep 15 00:00:40 hostname kdeinit5[1689]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Sep 15 00:00:42 hostname klauncher[1686]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Sep 15 00:00:42 hostname kglobalaccel5[1712]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Sep 15 00:00:43 hostname akonadi_control[2001]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Sep 15 00:00:46 hostname akonadiserver[2021]: org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Control process died, committing suicide!
Sep 15 00:00:47 hostname akonadi_followupreminder_agent[2037]: org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Akonadi server running without control process!
```

Answer (score 1):

The `/etc/sudoers` file is marked `%config(noreplace)`, which means that if it has been edited, a yum or dnf update would not overwrite it. You'd get `/etc/sudoers.rpmnew` instead.

Note that by default, Fedora ships with this line:

```
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)   ALL
```

which means that users in the `wheel` group have full sudo privileges. You note:

> ... I definately could use sudo before. I had to edit the sudoers file with the root user. It didn't have new user entries, it seemed to be a default file.

It's very possible that you could use sudo before *with* the default file without any specific user entry. My guess is that somehow you lost membership in the `wheel` group. This could have happened at any time, but wouldn't take affect until you log out and in again. I suspect that it's entirely unrelated to your crash, except that you rebooted after, and then logged back in now without that group.

Comment: I'm 99.9% sure that I added myself in the sudoers file when installing fedora. The group `wheel` is empty. I didn't need to reboot, but I had to log back in, yes. So your theory seems to be right, but I still have no idea what might have modified my sudoers/ maybe group file.